# 'Cypress Config File does not exist' - Lambdatest can't see cypress configuration file

Tags: vuejs2, cypress, vite, lambdatest

I've got installed Cypress on my Vue project and created just a few simple tests that perform great when I run Cypress with this command `npx cypress open`.

I am trying to implement automatisation with the help of Lambdatest but when I run command `lambdatest-cypress run` I receive this message in return:

```
Checking Lambda Config in current directory
Validating CLI
validating config
Error!! Cypress Config File does not exist
```

I have installed Lambdatest cli globally, added lambdatest-config.json in the root of my project, and updated "lambdatest_auth" data in this file. Also I've got cypress.config.js on the same root level in project's directory. Cypress's config file does not show any errors excluding eslint saying that
on this part

```
setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
  // implement node event listeners here
},
```

`on` and `config` are declared but never used.

Do you have any ideas why I can not run this one using Lambdatest?

Answer (score 0):

As always maybe someone will find it useful.
So... it would seem that in some cases lambdatest get's a little bit lost and it's config is not filled with the things it should be :)

The solution was to remove this line of code in lambdatest-config.json file which is located in the project root directory.
`"cypress_config_file": "cypress.config.js",` <-- remove this line